# Como fechar a navbar além do ícone hamburger, clicando fora do campo de menu?

Tags: javascript, menu, click

Recentemente segui um tutorial no YouTube referente à um menu que gostaria muito de utilizar; em modo responsivo é gerado um ícone hamburger, apresentando o menu navbar quando clicado e transformando o ícone em um X. O menu navbar é fechado somente quando clicado em um item do menu ou quando clicado no ícone X. Gostaria que além dessas duas formas, o menu também fechasse quando clicado fora do campo do menu (que foi definido com um width de 50vw). Tentei encontrar uma solução nos relatos parecidos, mas não consegui aplicar no meu código.

Segue código base pra conferência:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="/" class="logo">Logotipo</a>
            <div class="mobile-menu">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li><a href="/">Internet</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Soluções</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Portfólio</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main></main>
    <script src="/js/mobile-navbar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  body {
    background: #191930;
  }

  a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  a:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  
  .logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
  }
  
  nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #23232e;
    height: 8vh;
  }
  
  main {
    background: url("bg.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 92vh;
  }
  
  .nav-list {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .nav-list li {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin-left: 32px;
  }
  
  .mobile-menu {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .mobile-menu div {
    width: 32px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 8px;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 999px) {
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-list {
      position: absolute;
      top: 8vh;
      right: 0;
      width: 50vw;
      height: 92vh;
      background: #23232e;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      transform: translateX(100%);
      transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-list li {
      margin-left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .mobile-menu {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  
  .nav-list.active {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  
  @keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }
  
  .mobile-menu.active .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 8px);
  }
  
  .mobile-menu.active .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .mobile-menu.active .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -7px);
  }
```

Javascript:

```
class MobileNavbar {
    constructor(mobileMenu, navList, navLinks) {
      this.mobileMenu = document.querySelector(mobileMenu);
      this.navList = document.querySelector(navList);
      this.navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(navLinks);
      this.activeClass = "active";
  
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
  
    animateLinks() {
      this.navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        link.style.animation
          ? (link.style.animation = "")
          : (link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${
              index / 7 + 0.3
            }s`);
      });
    }
  
    handleClick() {
      this.navList.classList.toggle(this.activeClass);
      this.mobileMenu.classList.toggle(this.activeClass);
      this.animateLinks();
    }
  
    addClickEvent() {
      this.mobileMenu.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
    }
  
    init() {
      if (this.mobileMenu) {
        this.addClickEvent();
      }
    }
  }
  
  const mobileNavbar = new MobileNavbar(
    ".mobile-menu",
    ".nav-list",
    ".nav-list li",
  );

  mobileNavbar.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Embora a implementação da **`classe`** tenha ficado boa, não entendi por que utilizar a mesma, sendo que poderia ser feita apenas com funções, porém, quanto ao que deseja fazer, uma maneira simples é pegar o elemento `main` e associá-lo em um escutador de evento por exemplo.

```js
class MobileNavbar {
  constructor(mobileMenu, navList, navLinks, main) {
    this.mobileMenu = document.querySelector(mobileMenu);
    this.navList = document.querySelector(navList);
    this.navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(navLinks);
    this.main = document.getElementsByTagName(main);
    this.activeClass = "active";

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  animateLinks() {
    this.navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      link.style.animation ?
        (link.style.animation = "") :
        (link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`);
    });
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.navList.classList.toggle(this.activeClass);
    this.mobileMenu.classList.toggle(this.activeClass);
    this.animateLinks();
  }

  addClickEvent() {
    this.mobileMenu.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
  }
  
  // Método que escuta o click na tag main
  mainClick() {
    this.main[0].addEventListener("click", this.handleClick)
  }

  init() {
    if (this.mobileMenu) {
      this.addClickEvent();
    }
  }
}

const mobileNavbar = new MobileNavbar(
  ".mobile-menu",
  ".nav-list",
  ".nav-list li",
  "main"  // novo parâmetro
);

mobileNavbar.init();
mobileNavbar.mainClick();  // chama o método
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #191930;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #23232e;
  height: 8vh;
}

main {
  background: url("bg.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 92vh;
}

.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-list li {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-left: 32px;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-menu div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 8px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

@media (max-width: 999px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8vh;
    right: 0;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 92vh;
    background: #23232e;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-list li {
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .mobile-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-list.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.mobile-menu.active .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 8px);
}

.mobile-menu.active .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.mobile-menu.active .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -7px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href="/" class="logo">Logotipo</a>
      <div class="mobile-menu">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="/">Internet</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Soluções</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Portfólio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main></main>
  <script src="/js/mobile-navbar.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```